# How to include column name from oracle source to flat file (destination) in datastage?

Tags: etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I'm a total beginner and working my way to become a good ETL developer and i uses IBM Infosphere Datastage. I'm able to transfer/import data from databases(Oracle) to sequential file(csv) but i wanted to get the columns name? 
is there a way to do it ? i don't have anyone that taught me, i just do it by myself
So any idea would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sequential file stage, simply set the option "First Line is Column Names = True", compile and run the job then you will see the column names in the csv file.
[image]

Comment: Thankyou it works..
Really glad that someone comes to help :D

Comment: Hey Lee Kevin can you also please help me with this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705214/how-to-add-new-line-after-closing-tg-in-datastage-xml-output
I'm trying out many different things at the moment