# How to add new line after closing tg in Datastage xml output?

Tags: etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

So i've been making a XML output with the output layout/format/styling like this

```
<HAI>
 <TIME_SK>
  <INSERT_DATE>
20191021
  </INSERT_DATE>
  <SRC_STM_ID>
1
  </SRC_STM_ID>
<HAI>
 <TIME_SK>
  <INSERT_DATE>
20191021
  </INSERT_DATE>
  <SRC_STM_ID>
1
  </SRC_STM_ID>
```

but i wanted to make the output like this

```
<HAI>
 <TIME_SK>
  <INSERT_DATE> 20191021</INSERT_DATE>
  <SRC_STM_ID>1</SRC_STM_ID>
```

Someone have any idea? Thankyou

Comment: How does the headline refer to the result? Do you want to add or remove new lines?

Comment: My results is that it added a new line after the opening tag, then after the value, then after the closing tag.
But what i wanted is that the XML output to add a new line after the closing tag, to make it more tidy or prettier to read to users.